# Table identifiers with LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join

How does one join say, on **tableD.id = tableC.id AND tableD.id = tableE.id**? both tableD and E may have 0 rows and I need to count them ie. SELECT COUNT(E.id). The problem is I don't know where to declare the table identifiers.

I've tried:

**FROM tableB B, tableD D, tableE E ...**

**LEFT JOIN (tableC C, tableD D) ON ...**

```
SELECT B.*, COUNT(C.id) AS cCount 
FROM tableB B
LEFT JOIN (tableC C)
ON (B.id = C.id)
GROUP BY B.id
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide sample data, and your desired results?

Comment: It seems I've asked the wrong question, but what I need is to aggregate the joined rows D then count them, so I'll have the count of C and D. My answer lies somewhere with aggregation I guess.

Comment: You've now mentioned tables C and D, what about E?

Comment: count C and E sorry, D is just needed for the appropriate join.

Comment: More like add more conditions to the join of D and E, sorry i've left alot out of my question lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a little difficult to tell from your question what you're looking for, but I believe this is it:

```
SELECT B.*, COUNT(C.id) AS cCount 
FROM tableB AS B
LEFT JOIN tableC AS C ON B.id = C.id
LEFT JOIN tableD AS D ON C.Id = D.Id
LEFT JOIN tableE AS E ON D.Id = E.Id
GROUP BY B.id
```

Comment: For the join D and E, what if only table D is allowed to have no rows for a join to occur?

Comment: If D does not have any rows, this query will still work. Nothing will be returned for the D and E tables (because you're linking D with E, E cannot have any records returned that match D).

Comment: Problem is my count of C is being corrupted by the join of E and D. Hmm. Somehow I need to group the rows of E so D's row count is uncorrupted.